# Google Map place search box not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

It's been quite a research but to no avail. Trying to implement Google Map API however the search option still seems to be at large. Due to the Bootstrap usage it had added to more trouble.

> **As of now, the whole page is refreshing with search option not working**

***What I want to achieve is*** :

1. **`Only the map portion should refresh, when search button is clicked.`**
2. **`The search results should also display nearby places.`**

   ```
       <section class="no-padding adv--section">   
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
       <div id="offers-map" class="offers-map2"></div>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="tfheader">

       <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get">
               <input type="text" id="mapSearchBox" class="tftextinput" placeholder="Write Place Name To Search Parking................" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
       </form>
               <script>
                   function initAutocomplete() {
                       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapSearchBox'), {
                       center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
                       zoom: 13,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   });

               // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
                       var input = document.getElementById('maplocationsearch');
                       var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                       map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

               // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
                       map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
                       searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
                   });

                       var markers = [];

               // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve more details for that place.                                       
                       searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
                       var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
                           if (places.length == 0) {
                               return;
                           }

               // Clear out the old markers.
                       markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                       marker.setMap(null);
                  });

                   markers = [];

               // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                       places.forEach(function(place) {
                           var icon = {
                           url: place.icon,
                           size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                           origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                           anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                       };

               // Create a marker for each place.
                       markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                       map: map,
                       icon: icon,
                       title: place.name,
                       position: place.geometry.location
                   }));

                                           if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                                             // Only geocodes have viewport.
                                                   bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                                                       } else {
                                                   bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                                                   }
                                               });
                                         map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                       });
                                     }
                                   </script>                                           
                               <div class="tfclear"></div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>          
       </section>
   ```

**How do I get this rectified ? Please help !!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict search to nearby places by specifying [radius](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)